# How to calculate a post dominator tree in LLVM excluding some basic blocks?

Tags: algorithm, llvm, llvm-ir, unreachable-code

I built a post dominator tree for a function in my LLVM pass. However, the function has several blocks containing only unreachable instructions, which causes that the return block cannot post-dominate all basic blocks.

Therefore, what's the correct method to exclude such basic blocks in the post dominator tree? I've tried calling `removeUnreachableBlocks()` but it changed nothing.